# Why are my divs inheriting from the main css file but not the last div?

Tags: html, css, vue.js

Can somebody tell me why my last element wrapper/div "talk" is inheriting from the `base.css` file? It's wrapped in its own div under the parent wrapper: "encompass". However, it's inheriting from the base.css file over the one that the rest of the divs are inheriting from (about, projects, etc...)

```css
/************/
/* base.css */
/************/


/* color palette from <https://github.com/vuejs/theme> */

 :root {
  --vt-c-white: #ffffff;
  --vt-c-white-soft: #f8f8f8;
  --vt-c-white-mute: #f2f2f2;
  --vt-c-black: #181818;
  --vt-c-black-soft: #222222;
  --vt-c-black-mute: #282828;
  --vt-c-indigo: #2c3e50;
  --vt-c-divider-light-1: rgba(60, 60, 60, 0.29);
  --vt-c-divider-light-2: rgba(60, 60, 60, 0.12);
  --vt-c-divider-dark-1: rgba(84, 84, 84, 0.65);
  --vt-c-divider-dark-2: rgba(84, 84, 84, 0.48);
  --vt-c-text-light-1: var(--vt-c-indigo);
  --vt-c-text-light-2: rgba(60, 60, 60, 0.66);
  --vt-c-text-dark-1: var(--vt-c-white);
  --vt-c-text-dark-2: rgba(235, 235, 235, 0.64);
}


/* semantic color variables for this project */

 :root {
  --color-background: var(--vt-c-white);
  --color-background-soft: var(--vt-c-white-soft);
  --color-background-mute: var(--vt-c-white-mute);
  --color-border: var(--vt-c-divider-light-2);
  --color-border-hover: var(--vt-c-divider-light-1);
  --color-heading: var(--vt-c-text-light-1);
  --color-text: var(--vt-c-text-light-1);
  --section-gap: 160px;
}

@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
   :root {
    --color-background: var(--vt-c-black);
    --color-background-soft: var(--vt-c-black-soft);
    --color-background-mute: var(--vt-c-black-mute);
    --color-border: var(--vt-c-divider-dark-2);
    --color-border-hover: var(--vt-c-divider-dark-1);
    --color-heading: var(--vt-c-text-dark-1);
    --color-text: var(--vt-c-text-dark-2);
  }
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  font-weight: normal;
  position: relative;
}

body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  color: var(--color-text);
  background: var(--color-background-soft);
  transition: color 0.5s, background-color 0.5s;
  line-height: 1.6;
  font-family: Inter, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Fira Sans', 'Droid Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}



/************/
/* main.css */
/************/


/* Just has a bunch of normal stylings like- */

.talk-button {
  border: #ffff00;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: rgb(224, 224, 224);
  opacity: 80%;
  margin-top: 4rem;
  padding-top: 1rem;
  padding-left: 0.3rem;
  padding-right: 0.3rem;
  padding: 1rem;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.talk-desc {
  padding-top: 2rem;
  padding-bottom: 2rem;
  max-width: 65%;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: rgb(165, 165, 165);
}

.talk-subtitle {
  margin-top: 10rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="encompass">
  <div class="hero-section">
    <h1 class="small-heading">
      <span class=""></span>
      <span class="period" style="color: yellow"></span>
    </h1>
    <div class="big-heading">
      <h2>
      <span class="build"></span>
      <span class="random-text"></span>
      </h2>
    </div>
    <p class="main-desc"></p>
    <button class="linkedin"></button>
  </div>

  <div class="about">
    <h1 class="subtitle"></h1>
    <p class="about-desc"></p>
    <button class="coffee"></button>
  </div>

  <div class="projects">
    <h1 class="proj-subtitle"></h1>
    <p class="proj-desc"></p>
  </div>

  <div class="talk">
    <h1 class="talk-subtitle"></h1>
    <p class="talk-desc>"></p>
    <button class="talk-button"></button>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to tell exactly what you mean since the snippet doesn't really render anything and the CSS for each section isn't included, however, I do see two minor issues in the HTML code that could be causing rendering inconsistencies.

First, the Projects div doesn't have a button. And second the `<p>` inside the Talk div has a typo in the classname. it says `talk-desc>` instead of `talk-desc`.

That said, if I add the button in and remove the "talk" specific CSS from your file, they all render the same. So the container `talk` div is actually inheriting correctly, the rendering difference you are seeing is in the nested elements that you have added CSS stylings for.

```css
/************/
/* base.css */
/************/


/* color palette from <https://github.com/vuejs/theme> */

 :root {
  --vt-c-white: #ffffff;
  --vt-c-white-soft: #f8f8f8;
  --vt-c-white-mute: #f2f2f2;
  --vt-c-black: #181818;
  --vt-c-black-soft: #222222;
  --vt-c-black-mute: #282828;
  --vt-c-indigo: #2c3e50;
  --vt-c-divider-light-1: rgba(60, 60, 60, 0.29);
  --vt-c-divider-light-2: rgba(60, 60, 60, 0.12);
  --vt-c-divider-dark-1: rgba(84, 84, 84, 0.65);
  --vt-c-divider-dark-2: rgba(84, 84, 84, 0.48);
  --vt-c-text-light-1: var(--vt-c-indigo);
  --vt-c-text-light-2: rgba(60, 60, 60, 0.66);
  --vt-c-text-dark-1: var(--vt-c-white);
  --vt-c-text-dark-2: rgba(235, 235, 235, 0.64);
}


/* semantic color variables for this project */

 :root {
  --color-background: var(--vt-c-white);
  --color-background-soft: var(--vt-c-white-soft);
  --color-background-mute: var(--vt-c-white-mute);
  --color-border: var(--vt-c-divider-light-2);
  --color-border-hover: var(--vt-c-divider-light-1);
  --color-heading: var(--vt-c-text-light-1);
  --color-text: var(--vt-c-text-light-1);
  --section-gap: 160px;
}

@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
   :root {
    --color-background: var(--vt-c-black);
    --color-background-soft: var(--vt-c-black-soft);
    --color-background-mute: var(--vt-c-black-mute);
    --color-border: var(--vt-c-divider-dark-2);
    --color-border-hover: var(--vt-c-divider-dark-1);
    --color-heading: var(--vt-c-text-dark-1);
    --color-text: var(--vt-c-text-dark-2);
  }
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  font-weight: normal;
  position: relative;
}

body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  color: var(--color-text);
  background: var(--color-background-soft);
  transition: color 0.5s, background-color 0.5s;
  line-height: 1.6;
  font-family: Inter, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Fira Sans', 'Droid Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}



/************/
/* main.css */
/************/


/* Just has a bunch of normal stylings like- */

// .talk-button {
//   border: #ffff00;
//   border-width: 2px;
//   border-style: solid;
//   border-radius: 0.5rem;
//   background-color: transparent;
//   color: rgb(224, 224, 224);
//   opacity: 80%;
//   margin-top: 4rem;
//   padding-top: 1rem;
//   padding-left: 0.3rem;
//   padding-right: 0.3rem;
//   padding: 1rem;
//   font-size: 16px;
// }

// .talk-desc {
//   padding-top: 2rem;
//   padding-bottom: 2rem;
//   max-width: 65%;
//   font-size: 20px;
//   color: rgb(165, 165, 165);
// }

// .talk-subtitle {
//   margin-top: 10rem;
// }
```

```html
<div class="encompass">
  <div class="hero-section">
    <h1 class="small-heading">
      <span class=""></span>
      <span class="period" style="color: yellow"></span>
    </h1>
    <div class="big-heading">
      <h2>
      <span class="build"></span>
      <span class="random-text"></span>
      </h2>
    </div>
    <p class="main-desc"></p>
    <button class="linkedin">LinkedIn Button</button>
  </div>

  <div class="about">
    <h1 class="subtitle">About Subhead</h1>
    <p class="about-desc">About description</p>
    <button class="coffee">About Button</button>
  </div>

  <div class="projects">
    <h1 class="proj-subtitle">Projects Subhead</h1>
    <p class="proj-desc">Projects description</p>
        <button class="proj-button">Projects Button</button>
  </div>

  <div class="talk">
    <h1 class="talk-subtitle">Talk Subhead</h1>
    <p class="talk-desc">Talk description</p>
    <button class="talk-button">Talk Button</button>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Wow. I've been staring at that for so long... thanks for being my fresh set of eyes lol